# Inicializar LinkedList copiando a una LinkedList que retorna un metodo en Java

Tags: java

¿Es posible que desde un metodo como este

```
public LinkedList<File> getLista() {
    return lista;
}
```

se pueda inicializar otra LinkedList, como por ejemplo de esta manera?

```
LinkedList<File> laux = lista.getLista();
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puede parecer muy obvio pero sí, eso lo puedes hacer. 
Debes tener cuidado con el método `getLista()`, ya que puede que en RunTime no sepa que es 'lista'. 
Si está dentro de una clase, intenta usar `this.lista`, así haras referencia al objeto definido como private/protected/public en tu clase.